# what am I doing wrong with this import in my react component?

Tags: reactjs

What am I doing wrong with this import in my react component?  I'm trying to use the following npm package in my React app:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-headless-render-pdf

I'm assuming that this package is useable from a React app.  Is there any reason why it would not be?  If not then how should I evaluate whether or not an npm package is useable in a React app?  The npmjs page shows the package being used like this:

```
const RenderPDF = require('chrome-headless-render-pdf');
RenderPDF.generateSinglePdf('http://google.com', 'outputPdf.pdf');
```

I was thinking that I should be able to simply import the package in my React component like this:

```
import * from 'chrome-headless-render-pdf';
```

However, intellisense is reporting this import as invalid.  How can I properly import this package into my component?

Comment: import RenderPDF from 'chrome-headless-render-pdf';

Answer (score 2):

In their documentation, They also mentioned it as:

you can also use it from **typescript or es6**

```
import RenderPDF from 'chrome-headless-render-pdf';
RenderPDF.generateSinglePdf('http://google.com', 'outputPdf.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is not a valid import statement according to the ecmascript spec.

```
import * from 'chrome-headless-render-pdf';
```

When you use the `*` import syntax, you must assign a name. For example:

```
import * as chromeHeadless from 'chrome-headless-render-pdf';
```

This will make all named exports from the module available from your chosen namespace. You might use this with modules that does not have a `default` export. Typically the documentation for the module will explain which style of import syntax you can use.

[MDN provides a reference of the different valid import statements available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: If you are familiar with python's `import` statement, you might expect javascript to work exactly the same. There are superficial similarities, but also some fundamental differences. One difference is that python allows naked `from somemodule import *` statements. This is not possible in javascript.